# Insert icon into Java Swing JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I checked many previous questions here on stackoverflow but none has been a solution to the problem I have.
I must "simply" insert an icon in my JFrame, I tried to do it this way (from another stackoverflow question):

```
// ico file is in the same folder
ImageIcon frameIcon = new ImageIcon("/iconqm16.ico");
jFrame1.setIconImage(frameIcon.getImage());
```

but this didn't work. After this I tried the following:

```
URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("/iconqm(20x20).png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
jFrame1.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

This time I used .png because I read that .ico is Windows specific. And I used class resource because it can be packed in the jar.
But my icon doesn't appear yet. Someone can find any error in these snippets? Maybe it is a problem of image dimensions? I tried 16x16, 20x20, 32x32 but none worked.

**EDIT**

I found out the problem. Tried this code below and my program can't find the file even if the path is correct. I checked it well before editing my question, can you help me understand why can't find the image file?

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("C:/Users/Sergio/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Queue Manager v1.0/icon/icon16px.png");
    if (url == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find image!");
    } else {
        jFrame1.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(url).getImage());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This finally worked, but honestly I don't get the reason why `getClass().getResource(pathToFile)` did not work. Used this solution:

```
try {
    // Set Frame's Icon
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Sergio\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Queue Manager v1.0\\icon\\icon16px.png"));
    this.setIconImage(img);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(QueueManagerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use ImageIO to read the image file. If it can't read the image you will get an error message.

Comment: Can you make or redirect me to an example of how to use it to set the frame icon?

Comment: There is no trick. You use `ImageIO.read(...)` to read the `Image`, then you use the `setIconImage(...)` method. If you have never used ImageIO before then read the API or search the forum for examples. If you need more help post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. Note I have used 16x16 and 64x64 gif files and have not had any problems. I suggest you also read [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html). Maybe you have your class path is wrong. Are you able to display the Icon a JLabel?